# Storing TCP connection-id to retrieve it afterwards

Tags: spring-integration

Storing TCP connection-id to retrieve it afterwards

Hello,
A TCP server handles clients connection and store each connection-id into a database. Connection id is something like "localhost:58653:10001:fb10ac9b-b203-4df6-a360-13aa13855577".

In an other hand, the same server provides a HTML page that lists the connections with a "ping" button.
A click on a button will send a message to the client that matches the connection id.

Both processes are decorrelated.
So, I need to retrieve the TCP connection that matches the stored connection id.

I didn't find an access to the connections cache that is located in class "AbstractConnectionFactory".

Do you have some advices ?
Am I in a wrong way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TcpConnectionSupport` has these useful methods:

```
protected void publishConnectionOpenEvent() {
    TcpConnectionEvent event = new TcpConnectionOpenEvent(this,
            this.connectionFactoryName);
    doPublish(event);
}

protected void publishConnectionCloseEvent() {
    TcpConnectionEvent event = new TcpConnectionCloseEvent(this,
            this.connectionFactoryName);
    doPublish(event);
}

protected void publishConnectionExceptionEvent(Throwable t) {
    TcpConnectionEvent event = new TcpConnectionExceptionEvent(this,
            this.connectionFactoryName, t);
    doPublish(event);
}
```

So, you should just subscribe for all of them and do an appropriate logic in your target service.

The `connectionId` is as `TcpConnectionEvent.getConnectionId()`. The `TcpConnection` is as `(TcpConnection) TcpConnectionEvent.getSource()`.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much.
You help me to implement a **TcpConnectionEvent** listener that manages a connections cache.